# Gradle file is not executing through cmd

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have made a code on notepad and saved it as `build.gradle` and when I try to run through the `cmd` it shows an error `Could not determine which task to run`. I am sharing the code with you

```
 task hello {
    doLast {
       println 'tutorialspoint'
    }
 }
```

In cmd prompt I am writing:- gradle -q hello to execute the task

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: I ran the same command as you did and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Just double-checking: are you running the `gradle` command from the same directory containing your build file?

Comment: yes I am running the file from the same directory where it is placed

Comment: I am using Gradle 1.9 version @VinayPrajapati

Comment: @RomitGupta please upgrade to Gradle 2.10

Comment: @RomitGupta please close this if it works fine for you or put an answer if you solved something, technically

Answer (score -1):

Run command

```
gradle hello
```

If you want to execute your **hello** task.

Comment: it is not running 
and please let me know I am making a notepad file for gradle is it the right approach?

Comment: What happens when you execute this command? What you see in the console?

Comment: Error arising- Could not determine which task to run